# Copy Calendar Recurrence Data from one list to another using CSOM SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, list-item

I am trying to copy Calendar  items from one list to another list in SharePoint online uisng CSOM. All the fields data copying as excepted but the Recurrence field data appearing as  `#RENDER FAILED` as shown in image.
[image: Calendar]

Please note that i am trying to copy items from one site collection to another site collection 
Below is my code:

```
                    try
                    {
                    itemToCreate["Title"] = SourcelistItem["Title"];
                    itemToCreate["Location"] = SourcelistItem["Location"];
                    itemToCreate["EventDate"] = SourcelistItem.FieldValues["EventDate"];
                    itemToCreate["EndDate"] = SourcelistItem.FieldValues["EndDate"];
                    itemToCreate["fRecurrence"] = SourcelistItem.FieldValues["fRecurrence"];
                    itemToCreate["RecurrenceData"] = SourcelistItem.FieldValues["RecurrenceData"];

                    itemToCreate["TimeZone"] = SourcelistItem.FieldValues["TimeZone"];
                    itemToCreate["XMLTZone"] = SourcelistItem.FieldValues["XMLTZone"];
                    itemToCreate["UID"] = SourcelistItem.FieldValues["UID"];
                    itemToCreate["Duration"]= SourcelistItem.FieldValues["Duration"];
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        lbl_Error.Text += ex.Message.ToString();
                    }                       

                itemToCreate.Update();
                destinationContext.Load(itemToCreate);
                destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Do i need to include any other columns for copying the Recurrence data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After including `EventType` the issue was fixed. The full code is as below

```
try
{
itemToCreate["Title"] = SourcelistItem["Title"];
itemToCreate["Location"] = SourcelistItem["Location"];
itemToCreate["EventDate"] = SourcelistItem.FieldValues["EventDate"];
itemToCreate["EndDate"] = SourcelistItem.FieldValues["EndDate"];
itemToCreate["fRecurrence"] = SourcelistItem.FieldValues["fRecurrence"];
itemToCreate["RecurrenceData"] = SourcelistItem.FieldValues["RecurrenceData"];    
itemToCreate["TimeZone"] = SourcelistItem.FieldValues["TimeZone"];
itemToCreate["XMLTZone"] = SourcelistItem.FieldValues["XMLTZone"];
itemToCreate["UID"] = SourcelistItem.FieldValues["UID"];
itemToCreate["Duration"]= SourcelistItem.FieldValues["Duration"];
itemToCreate["EventType"]= SourcelistItem.FieldValues["EventType"];
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

lbl_Error.Text += ex.Message.ToString();
}                       

itemToCreate.Update();
destinationContext.Load(itemToCreate);
destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you copy the "fRecurrence" flag it do only true/false flag. In the form when you check the option it will ask for which day and how many days it occur. System uses that additional information to render as shown in source site screenshot (e.g: Every 1 day(s)).

I am not exactly sure how to copy that additional info but I will update my answer if I can get it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated my code and tested now nothing is happening.. recurrence filed is empty

Comment: Can you check how the RecurrenceData XML stored in the destination list. This is going to be parsed and display on screen.